# Robocopy not outputting log as a .txt file

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a PowerShell script that gets usernames from a .CSV file and uses the username to robocopy that users data from our old server to the new one. The usernames are formatted as "firstname.lastname" within the organisation. I need the log files for each users robocopy to output as "firstname.lastname-dd-MM-HH:mm.txt"

However when I run my PowerShell script that gets the username from CSV, everything after the firstname becomes the file extension, despite PowerShell showing that it was logged as a .txt.

The script:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Veritech\RoboCopy\Users\UserTest.csv
$dt = get-date -f dd-MM-HH:mm

foreach ($UserName in $users) {

robocopy "\\*****\profile$\$UserName" "E:\Shares\Profile$\$UserName" /E /COPYALL /ZB /TEE /R:3 /W:5 /L /NS /NJS /NJH /NDL /FP /log+:"C:\*****\RoboCopy\Users\P-$UserName-$dt.txt"
}
```

PowerShell log, when run manually, not via task scheduler or .ps1 as intended:
[image]

Comment: Hard to say why your script isn't working when we can't see the code. Please see [mre] and [edit] your post to provide that code. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: @KenWhite, apologies. I thought I'd added the code. Updated now.

Comment: The log looks fine. Can you clarify your problem? What is NOT working as intended?

Comment: Have you disabled "Hide Extensions for Known File Types" in the Folder Options of Windows Explorer? `.txt` is a well known file extension and is not displayed by default, therefore you only see the base file name. Since you have a dot in the base filename between first and last name, it just seems to look like a file extension.